# I am trying to list all the tutor names whose salary is greater than the average salary and show how much the salary is greater than by

Tags: sql

The part thats giving me the most trouble is showing how much greater by is the salary I don't know how to do it

This is the code I have write down atm for the tutor's salary which is greater than the average just need to show how much greater by :

```
SELECT tName, Salary
FROM Tutor
WHERE salary > (SELECT avg(Salary) FROM Tutor;
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect is this? Can you use two queries with a variable - or does it have to be a single query?

Comment: Also, try to avoid Correlated Subquries (a SELECT statement inside of another SELECT clause or WHERE clause), but normal Subqueries (a SELECT inside a FROM) are okay.

Comment: It can be two queries I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close - one possible syntax is:

```
SELECT tName, Salary - ((SELECT avg(Salary) FROM Tutor) as SalaryDiff
FROM Tutor
WHERE Salary > (SELECT avg(Salary) FROM Tutor;
```

Depending on your SQL dialect there may be better ways of doing this! [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647693/how-to-calculate-average-of-a-column-and-then-include-it-in-a-select-query-in-or) for alternative methods.

Comment: tyvm I learnt something from this query I can do now tyvm man Bless.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a variable to avoid a potentially inefficient query execution plan:

```
DECLARE @avgSalary money
SELECT @avgSalary = AVG( salary ) FROM Tutor

SELECT
    tName,
    salary,
    @avgSalary,
    salary - @avgSalary AS salaryDiff
FROM
    Tutor
WHERE
    salary > @avgSalary
```