# What is difference for below there two sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select 
    substr(insert_date, 1, 14), 
    device, count(1) 
from 
    abc.xyztable   
where 
    insert_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
group by 
    device, substr(insert_date, 1, 14) ;
```

and then I am trying to get average of the same rows count which I got above.

```
SELECT 
    date, device, AVG(count) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         substr(insert_date, 1, 14) AS date,
         device,
         COUNT(1) AS count 
     FROM
         abc.xyztable
     WHERE
         insert_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
     GROUP BY
         device, substr(insert_date, 1, 14)) a
 GROUP BY 
     device, date;
```

AS I found both queries return the same results, I tried for last 10 days data.

My purpose is to get the average rows count for last 10 days which I get from the above 1st query.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What do you intend with ```count(1)```?

Comment: So your question is not what the difference between them as you stated but rather how to get average out of the first query's count result?

Comment: ate_tag_no, is updated
I used device instead this.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher, its simple as count (*).
and my question is to find the avrage of each result in 1st query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an average you need to change the last GROUP BY

to get an average per device

```
GROUP BY device;
```

to get an average per date

```
GROUP BY date;
```

or remove it completely to get an average for all rows in the sub-query

**Update**
Below is a full example for getting the average per device

```
SELECT device, avg(count)
FROM (SELECT substr(insert_date,1,14) as date, device, count(1) as count 
      FROM abc.xyztable
      WHERE insert_date >=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
      GROUP BY device,substr(insert_date,1,14)) a
GROUP BY device;
```

Comment: I am getting results, but those reults or same as 1st query.
I am just confused how to get average count per device in last 10 days.

Comment: @bilalshakir, I have update my answer with the full query. In my testing it doesn't return the same result as your first query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, the "difference" between the two queries is that the first one is valid but the second does not appear to be, as per HoneyBadger's comment. They also seem to be trying to achieve two different goals.

However, I think what you are trying to do is produce a query based on the data from the first query, which returns the date, device, and an average of the count column. If so, I believe the following query would calculate this:

```
WITH
   dataset AS (
       select substr(insert_date,1,14) AS theDate, device, count(*) AS 
       theCount 
       from abc.xyztable
       where insert_date >=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
       group by device,substr(insert_date,1,14)
       )

       SELECT theDate, device, (SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(theCount 
       AS FLOAT)), 2) FROM 
       dataset) AS Average
       FROM dataset
       GROUP BY theDate, device
```

I have referenced the accepted answers of this question to calculate the average: [How to calculate average of a column and then include it in a select query in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647693/how-to-calculate-average-of-a-column-and-then-include-it-in-a-select-query-in-or)
And this question to tidy up the query: [Formatting Clear and readable SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461481/formatting-clear-and-readable-sql-queries)

Without having a sample of your data, or any proper context, I can't see how this would be especially useful, so if it was not what you were looking for, please edit your question and clarify exactly what you need.

**EDIT**: Based on what extra information you have provided, I've made a tweak to my solution to increase the precision of the average column. It now calculates the average to two decimal places. You have stated that this returns the same result as your original query, but the two queries are not formulating the same thing. If the count column is consistently the same number with little variation, the AVG function will round this, which in turn *could* produce results which look the same, especially if you only compare a small sample, so I have amended my answer to demonstrate this. Again, we'd all be able to help you much easier if you would provide more information, such as a sample of your data.

Comment: thank you, but your updated query results are same as I am getting from my 2nd.

Comment: @bilalshakir you have edited your query to be valid, so what is wrong with the result? How does it differ from what you are trying to achieve?